# list index out of range - pre-order traversal of BST

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree, traversal

I am trying to pre-order traverse a BST that I get in the form of an array:
[image]

example input:
`["5","2","6","1","9","#","8","#","#","#","#","4","#"]` where `#` is an absent node in the tree

My output should be the result of the pre-order traversal:

`5 2 1 9 6 8 4`

So far I have been successful, except for the very last node, I get index out of range.
Here is my code so far:

```
 def traverse(strArr):
  strArr.insert(0, '#')

  def preorder(arr, ind):
    if ind <= len(arr) and arr[ind] != '#':
      print(arr[ind])
      preorder(arr, 2*ind)
      preorder(arr, 2*ind+1)

  preorder(strArr, 1)

traverse(["5","2","6","1","9","#","8","#","#","#","#","4","#"])
```

What do I need to change in order for the last node (4 in this case) to show without errors?

Comment: `ind <= len(arr)` allows `ind < len(arr)` and `ind == len(arr)`. Is `ind == len(arr)` valid? (Remember, this is the length *after* inserting an empty value at the start.)

Comment: "What do I need to change in order for the last node (4 in this case) to show without errors?" Well, in your own words, why does the error occur for this node, but not for other nodes? Hint: what value is being calculated for the index in this case? Is it in range? Does it make sense that the calculated index would be in range in other cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are two issues.

1. Arrays are zero-based:
   `if ind <= len(arr) and arr[ind] != '#':` allows `ind` to become `len(arr)` which is larger than the index of the last element of `arr`. In the same line you use `ind` as an index to access the array `arr[ind]`, which results in an `IndexError`. The fix here is to check if `ind` is **less than** `len(arr)`:

```
if ind < len(arr) and arr[ind] != '#':
```

2. The `4` is at the wrong index:
   It is currently at index `11` but should be at index `13`. Fix here:

```
traverse(["5","2","6","1","9","#","8","#","#","#","#","#","#","4","#"])
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct. The example I gave was wrong!! Thank you so much, fixed it now